# Can Banshee fix music metadata information?

Tags: banshee, metadata

I'd like Banshee to automatically find and fix the correct song title and artist names and album information for my music from the internet. Is this possible with this software?

Something like, 'find music metadata'.

Comment: Do you mean like you have edited the meta tags on your filesystem or you want information for your tracks from the internet?

Comment: The latter [5 chars].

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you have a [Last.fm](http://last.fm/) account, try the [Last.fm Fingerprint Extension](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/banshee-extension-lastfmfingerprint) [image: Install Last.fm Fingerprint Extension] for Banshee.

After installing this extension, enable it in Banshee by going to Edit > Preferences > Extensions and checking the box next to Last.fm Fingerprint.  With this extension enabled, you can right click on any song in your library and choose "Get Information from Track Fingerprint" which will find the song on Last.fm and fix your local metadata if it is incorrect.

[image: Install Last.fm Fingerprint Extension]

Comment: this would be great if it didn't time out so quickly and you weren't prompted for username and password each time.  It's quicker to edit the files by hand.

Answer (score 9):

There is standalone program for that (not Banshee) - Picard, in Ubuntu repos.
http://musicbrainz.org/doc/MusicBrainz_Picard

Comment: Picard is great, the only problem is that sometimes Banshee doesn't notice when 3rd-party apps update metadata: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=649806

There has been talk of building a Picard-like tool for Banshee (that uses MusicBrainz as its backend), but so far that hasn't happened.

Comment: Picard is for batch updating :) After that you can rescan your collection in Banshee (to avoid this bug)

Comment: No, take a look at the duplicate, even rescanning apparently doesn't work sometimes. :-/

Comment: (But I agree that batch updating is definitely the way to go.  It would be spectacular if Banshee's built-in metadata fixup would be a little more like Picard.)