# How to get music metadata in Banshee?

Tags: banshee, music, metadata

I'm using Banshee 2.2.1 on Ubuntu 11.10. When I tried to import my music library, which I
made by ripping CDs with Windows Media Player, only two albums retained their information. The rest (about 300 songs) were dumped into the unknown artist, unknown album folder. All of them have names and some have genre information. The two albums mentioned retained everything: artist, album, names, art, etc. I am not completely sure with what I ripped these albums.

Answer (score 1):

If you select the Unknown Album of the Unknown Artist, Banshee will display the corresponding track-list (which should contain all the unidentified tracks you imported).

[image: Select Unknown Album]

Select all the unknown tracks which you believe belong to a same album (using shift+left-click or ctrl+left-click), then right-click to get the context-menu. In this menu you will choose **Edit Track Information**:

[image: Edit Track Information]

You will then see an Edit Track Information dialogue, where you will be able to edit your metadata manually:

[image: Edit metadata]

There are also plug-ins to [fix metadata](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47571/can-banshee-fix-music-metadata-information).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I'm afraid that'd take quite a long time. There are 300 songs after all. I'm trying to convert the library to mp3s and adding tags right now. I hope someone else will be able to use your beautifully formatted advice.

Comment: @valtteri read the last line again, about the plugins. This will automate the process.

Comment: @valtteri: perhaps you should consider re-doing the ripping process differently, with a different software, in case the data was lost during that process?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I did read the link, but wasn't in the mood for creating accounts. I converted everything into mp3 (from wav) and tagged the information on the files themselves. Now everything works fine. I used SoundConverter, Audio Tag Tool and Easytag (for cover art) from the Ubuntu Software Center in case anyone is interested.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [EasyTag](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/easytag/), it is a ver easy to use metadata manager/editor. You can edit many files in one step. I have around 3000 music files, all edited with it.