# Get track information from Internet in 'Rhythmbox'

Tags: rhythmbox

In Banshee, I would right-click and obtain Track Information, including artist and album updates, from the internet.

This is explained in this Q&A - the lastfm-fingerprint extension:

[image]

- [Can Banshee fix music metadata information?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47571/can-banshee-fix-music-metadata-information)

How do I get so for Rhythmbox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Fingerprinting in Rhythmbox

An enterprising rhythmbox plugin developer has created a very [useful plugin](https://github.com/asermax/lastfm_extension) that has just this very feature.

### step by step

Installation instructions at the bottom of this answer.

Once installed, enable the plugin and click the *Preferences* button

[image]

Tick the checkbox shown above and click the *Login* button.  This will fire-up your favourite browser.

Login to LastFM:

[image]

Then allow the plugin access to LastFM:

[image]

Finally, click the button shown to finish the Rhythmbox configuration:

[image]

**How to finger print a song**

You will now have a new right-click option that searches LastFM:

[image]

When it finds possible matches, it presents this in most-likely order:

[image]

By default, it will update the artist, album and title of the song.

There is an extra check-box which does a deeper search of LastFM to find additional information about your song.

**how to install**

Full instructions are in the README file.

Some tips - install the package `python2.7-dev` before trying to install [pylastfp](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pylastfp/0.1).  You need version 0.6 or later of pylast.

Open a terminal then copy and paste a line at a time the following:

```
sudo apt-get install python2.7-dev git
git clone git://github.com/asermax/lastfm_extension.git
cd lastfm_extension
./install.sh
```

Then download v0.6 of pylast, extract it and then install via:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip libfftw3-dev libsamplerate0-dev
sudo pip install pylastfp
```

If compilation of packages is just not your cup-of-tea - then you can install my Rhythmbox PPA (link below) and install the `lastfm-extension` package which will install all the prerequisites for you.

---

Related Question:

- [How do I install third-party rhythmbox plugins?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147942/how-do-i-install-third-party-rhythmbox-plugins)

Comment: A few additions obtained from @fossfreedom in the Ubuntu Chat Room:

If you don't have git-clone, run:

* sudo apt-get install git
after which, in the terminal, type:


* git clone git://github.com/asermax/lastfm_extension.git
* cd lastfm_extension
  
* ./install.sh

Works now.

Comment: the plugin in the accepted answer doesn't work with rhythm box 3.0 + https://github.com/asermax/lastfm_extension/issues/22

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Rhythmbox can only update art work for your albums.
This is done with the help of a plugin. They are installed and enabled by default.
So **the quick answer** to your question if Rhythmbox can fix the music tags **is NO**.

To open the plugins window go to Edit / Plugins.

In case they are not installed:

```
sudo apt-get install rhythmbox-plugins
```

About the Rhythmbox 3rd party plugins:
https://live.gnome.org/RhythmboxPlugins/ThirdParty